# Laravel getting Class Broadcast not found after upgrade from 5.3 to 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I keep getting `class Broadcast not found` in Laravel 5.4 when I reload my project after I upgraded from 5.3.

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Class 'Broadcast' not found
```

Comment: Have you made sure to run things like `composer dump-autoload` after the upgrade. You may be missing classes in your autoloader.

Comment: Make sure you update composer and clear out anything cached.

Comment: Thanks Piotr and Hanny, the error is from the `routes/channels.php file`. Tried running `composer dump-autoload` but am still getting the error. Tried running `php artisan config:cache` and composer update to. I have commented the contents of the file to continue working on the project for now.

Answer (score 4):

Just ran in to the same issue. Most likely this you need to add the Broadcast alias to your `config/app.php` file

```
'aliases' => [
    'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the Broadcast facade isn't making it through from the `BroadcastServiceProvider.php` to your auth listings in `channels.php`. The quick easy fix is to directly require the Broadcast facade in your channels.php file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

/*
All of your broadcast auth stuff here
*/
```

Comment: Worked after i cleared the route cache `php artisan route:clear`. Guess your solution would also work